# Nav bar background fades on scroll but not visible on page reload

Tags: jquery, css

I have a all-white nav with a transparent background that adopts a black fade-in background when it reaches past a header div (usually containing an image that serves as background), determined by the height of that header div. However, when the page is reloaded, the page has to be scrolled again in order for the nav to have a background. Obviously this is a problem if the reloaded page's state is below the header (the body has a white background, per client). How can I have the background remain if the nav is below the header div? Thanks for any insight.

jQuery:

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('.nav-null');
var Heightofit = startchange.outerHeight()-100;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll_start > Heightofit) {
        $('nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
    } else {
        $('nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
nav {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index:1000;
padding:0 32px;
padding: 0 2rem;
-webkit-transition-duration: .4s;
        transition-duration: .4s;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a complete example that demonstrates the issue? Preferable as a snippet here in the question.

Comment: "I have a all-white nav with a transparent background", is it white or is it transparent?

Comment: without HTML of the nav and complete css it will take hours to give you a solution. You should create a JSFiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lq8mab34/1/ -based on a fiddle by user Mohamed-Yousef.